# How to limit value types in director-based routing in Qwik?

Tags: qwik

If you want to have a blog with pagination, this can be one routing example in Qwik:

```
- src
  - routes
    - blog
      - index.jsx
      - [pageNumber]
        - index.jsx
```

And it works for `/blog` and `/blog/2` URLs.

The problem is that, it also works for `/blog/john` and `/blog/j!o*hn` too.

In other words, it's not limited to numbers only.

How can I limit route values to specific types only?

Answer (score 1):

I believe which on query string you going to have always a string type. After that you should use `useLocation().params.pageNumber` and then check if is a number o string.